# Making raster from almost regular point data using R

Tags: raster, r

the following code gives an error:

```
library(raster)
m<-structure(c(5206460.273682, 4611410.70441311, 2905601.93917564, 
4393225.86234785, 2905601.93917564, 2970602.35408714, 4210288.95673065, 
2127615.46428955, 2772252.49766417, 1780503.21554936, -0.552776856473696, 
-1.63197925019317, 0.116332861687154, -0.339757554172166, 1.0130490754329
), .Dim = c(5L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("x", "y", "value"
)))
rasterFromXYZ(m)
```

The data is created using the st_sample method from the sf-package and therefore should be regular (I used the regular-option).
However, I guess the grid-points are not regularly spaced.

Which point is the problem?

Is there a simple way to place the points to be regular?

Answer (score 2):

If you set the `digits` option low enough, it will rasterise:

```
> r = rasterFromXYZ(m,digits=-1)
> plot(r)
> points(m[,1],m[,2])
```

[image]

But the points do not seem to lie on the points of a regular grid except with a very very small grid size.